# How to reset layer color in mapbox GL JS client-side?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm writing a program which is based on Mapbox GL JS. I have saved my layer in mapbox styles and given them some coloring.
On client side,on click of button I'm changing color of that layer by
`Map.setPaintProperty(layerid,'circle-color','#ff00ff')`
but now I want one more button which will reset the layer color back to original (which I gave in mapbox style).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to store the original color yourself. Before setting the new color do:

```
const originalColor = map.getPaintProperty(layerid, 'circle-color');
// ...set the color on click

// on reset
map.setPaintProperty(layerid, 'circle-color', originalColore);
```

Alternatively you can store the complete original map style by using `map.getStyle()` and then resetting it with `map.setStyle(originalStyle)`: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getstyle

Comment: This is correct, mapbox-gl-js doesn't store any notion of "original" for you.